# Sort references alphabetically

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am using the IEEE [template](https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html), where the bibliography section is like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{b1} G. Eason, B. Noble, and I. N. Sneddon, ``On certain integrals of Lipschitz-Hankel type involving products of Bessel functions,'' Phil. Trans. Roy. Soc. London, vol. A247, pp. 529--551, April 1955.
\bibitem{b2} J. Clerk Maxwell, A Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism, 3rd ed., vol. 2. Oxford: Clarendon, 1892, pp.68--73.
\bibitem{b3} I. S. Jacobs and C. P. Bean, ``Fine particles, thin films and exchange anisotropy,'' in Magnetism, vol. III, G. T. Rado and H. Suhl, Eds. New York: Academic, 1963, pp. 271--350.
\bibitem{b4} K. Elissa, ``Title of paper if known,'' unpublished.
\bibitem{b5} R. Nicole, ``Title of paper with only first word capitalized,'' J. Name Stand. Abbrev., in press.
\bibitem{b6} Y. Yorozu, M. Hirano, K. Oka, and Y. Tagawa, ``Electron spectroscopy studies on magneto-optical media and plastic substrate interface,'' IEEE Transl. J. Magn. Japan, vol. 2, pp. 740--741, August 1987 [Digests 9th Annual Conf. Magnetics Japan, p. 301, 1982].
\bibitem{b7} M. Young, The Technical Writer's Handbook. Mill Valley, CA: University Science, 1989.
\end{thebibliography}
```

and the output is

[image]

I would like to sort the references alphabetically. How can I do that?

Comment: If you input the bibliography data manually like that, it’s your responsibility to sort it.

Comment: Let BibLaTeX or BibTeX do the work for you.